# with Subversion, how to manage version of component in a multiproject repository?

Tags: svn, version-control, project-organization

Imagine an organization of a repository like this:

```
/Project1/branches
          /tags/Rel-1.0
          /trunk
/Module1/branches
           /tags/Rel-1.0
           /tags/Rel-1.1
           /tags/Rel-2.0
           /trunk
/Module2/branches
           /tags/Rel-1.0
           /tags/Rel-1.1
           /tags/Rel-1.2  
           /tags/Rel-1.3
           /tags/Rel-2.0
           /tags/Rel-2.1         
           /trunk
```

The project1 is using Module1 and Module2.
The release 1.0 of project1 is done by using release 1.0 of Module1 and Module2.

The new release of project1 (named for example 1.1, not a major evolution) is done by using Release 2.0 of Module1 and 2.1 of Module2.

How can do this by using subversion.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to solve dependency management outside SVN (think of Apache Maven or Ivy in the Javaverse).

If it has to be SVN, how about special tag names? So you could introduce a convention that your build system looks in special folders for versions it depends on, like `/Module1/branches/deps/Project1/Rel-1.0` for the code your Rel-1.0 build of Project1 needs.

```
/Project1/branches
          /tags/Rel-1.0
          /trunk
/Module1/branches
           /tags/Rel-1.0
           ...
           /tags/Rel-2.0
           /deps/Project1/Rel-1.0
           /deps/Project1/Rel-1.1
           /trunk
/Module2/branches
           /tags/Rel-1.0
           ...
           /tags/Rel-2.1         
           /deps/Project1/Rel-1.0
           /deps/Project1/Rel-1.1
           /trunk
```

You could create the folders for dependents by referencing to the tag folders:

```
# dependencies to Module1
svn cp http://myServer/svn/Module1/branches/tags/Rel-1.0 http://myServer/svn/Module1/branches/deps/Project1/Rel-1.0
svn cp http://myServer/svn/Module1/branches/tags/Rel-2.0 http://myServer/svn/Module1/branches/deps/Project1/Rel-1.1
# dependencies to Module2
svn cp http://myServer/svn/Module2/branches/tags/Rel-1.0 http://myServer/svn/Module1/branches/deps/Project1/Rel-1.0
svn cp http://myServer/svn/Module2/branches/tags/Rel-2.0 http://myServer/svn/Module1/branches/deps/Project1/Rel-1.1
```

Switching versions later would look like

```
# delete old reference
svn rm http://myServer/svn/Module1/branches/deps/Project1/Rel-1.1
# make other one for new version
svn cp http://myServer/svn/Module1/branches/tags/Rel-2.1 http://myServer/svn/Module1/branches/deps/Project1/Rel-1.1
```

The downside of this approach could be more space requirement for SVN working directories.

Comment: My projects are in C++. Some components are also third-party library. 
My first objective is to find the best project&library organization for the repository.
My second goal is to see if under SVN I can easily know and manage automatically how is composed an application (which modules are embedded and with which version)

Comment: I guess the problem with this approach is, that SVN is not built for this stuff. You will have to create some own build process (be it with make, cmake or something different) that reads Metadata from the Repo or a working copy and builds the right stuff accordingly.

At least the reading can be done nicely via XML (like `svn ls --xml http://server/repo/path/to/list` on the command line).

Another approach could be that you put a file in your project's or module's path which describes it's current dependencies. That could in turn be read by the build tool and acted upon.

Comment: I completely forgot the obvious solution: if you use a build tool like make, you already got a file under version control you can put the dependency descriptions in: _the makefile_... :o)

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest reorganisation of repo by splitting to separate repos for each "entity" (Project, Module1, Module2,...,ModuleN) and use svn:externals in Project repo for all modules instead of direct embedding code.

At development stage externals refer to HEAD of external repo, in every release of Project (marked as special tag, yes?) before tagging Project you have to edit and freeze externals to some fixed revision of included modules.

Pro

- you'll separate deleopment history (in terms of SVN) into independent sub-parts
- for every tagged release linked versions of modules are easily identifiable
- repos will have more a simple code-tree
- /something forgotten/

Contra

- history of project will not be transparent due to the presence of a bifurcation point and work with ancient revisions (before bifurcation) will give (can give) some headache